# GUI is shown on EDT

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I have read this statement that "GUI is shown on EDT". Could anyone please explain me this statement, I know that event listeners are executed on EDT but how GUI can be shown on EDT.

Comment: see Oracle tutorial [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and read Q&A by click to tag EventDispatchThread (addded to your question)

Comment: I read  that , the document says you should not perform lengthy task on EDT otherwise GUI can freeze. But events should keep on going into the event queue.

Comment: `(But events should keep on going into the event queue.)` EDT flush all events in the one moment to the screen, then/after is EDT empty

Comment: 'I have read this statement that "GUI is shown on EDT"'. Seems misleading as EDT is not the one who decide how the GUI is shown, but only a thread that the programmer *must* use to manipulate GUI components (according to Java guidelines). Hence the question should be (?) 'Is it mandatory that programs create/update GUI components using only the EDT?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "GUI is shown on the EDT" is imprecise and misleading. The actual truth is that all operations on GUI objects, including their instantiation, must happen on the EDT. From this it follows that all actions resulting in GUI elements being shown on the screen also happen on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

The EDT is responsible for everything. It takes any events (mouse/keyboard clicks etc) and then calls any actions based on the events. If you wish to do anything on the UI (show a button etc from the code), the EDT again is responsible to show it on screen.

Ideally all of your button initialization (UI actions etc) should be done by the EDT though is not mandatory (In android it is). The document says not to perform lengthy tasks is for: As mentioned because EDT handles everything, if EDT is busy with lengthy task, then any mouse clicks etc cannot be processed by EDT creating hangs in UI experience